# htaccess 301 redirect Find and Replace

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website which refers to to various Indian cities. Code makes links from an external source, which may name a city as Calcutta, calcuta, Kolkata, etc.

I need a htaccess 301 redirect rule which, given all the misspellings would redirect the following the known good spelling (Kolkata):

Calcutta-to-Delhi.html to Kolkata-to-Delhi.html

and also

Calcuta-Airport.html to Kolkata-Airport.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is not simple and need you to have a powerful computer, but the results are simply amazing.

Here's what I'd suggest to do:

- You have to test if your expression matches in the URL `/` i.e. `http://mysite.com/(expr1)-to-(expr2)/`
- If yes and there's no file, redirect to a Php file that handles everything.
- In this Php file, analyze the URL (once again): if your expression matches `/(expr1)-to-(expr2)/` then do a [SOUNDEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) search with MySQL (in your `Php` file). See query sample [here](http://tendena.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/mysql-phonetic-search/).
- Then, in this "special" 404 case, do a suggestion, like google does, i.e.: "did you mean `Kolkata-to-Delhi.html`? if so, click on the link".

This a hard work, but it's both interesting and shows your skill. Very few websites do this (I just know google actually).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
# REDIRECTS FROM (eg): http://www.calcutta.com.au/ to http://www.kolkata.com.au/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^calcutta\.com\.au$ [nocase, ornext]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.calcutta\.com\.au$ [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.kolkata.com.au/ [nocase,L,R=301,O]
```

Notice the "[nocase]" which ignores case. This will only redirect from "calcutta" to "kolkata" and not from "calcuta" or "Kolkata" (notice the missing 't' in calcuta and uppercase 'K' in Kolkata).

You will need to add two more rules following the same pattern of code as above.